# getting the solution from Wolfram alpha in python

Tags: python, python-3.7, wolframalpha

So I am working on an assistant where the user will ask for an answer for a math problem and wolfram alpha will return it.

---

My problem right now is: Wolfram alpha returns the next step of the math problem.

What I want: Wolfram alpha should return the answer in decimal or integer after solving the whole problem.

My code:

```
import wolframalpha

query = input("calculate: ")

client = wolframalpha.Client("TYXXXX-PXXXXXXXX2")

query = query.replace(" ", "")
res = client.query(' '.join(query))
answer = next(res.results).text
print("calculating..")
print(f"The answer is {answer}")
```

Example:

```
input: 2x = 5
```

The answer I am looking for:

```
output: 2.5
```

The answer I get right now: output: `5/2`

```
input: 2x = 5 - 3
```

The answer I am looking for: `output: x = 1`

The answer I get: `2x = 2`

Comment: Do you want to get a solution from Wolfram or do you want to get a solution for a symbolic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you can have the final solution provided by WolframAlpha (you just need to get the last element of the generator, instead of retrieving only the first one):

```
import wolframalpha

client = wolframalpha.Client(AppID)

response = client.query(input())

# Get the last item of the generator res.results
result = None
for result in response.results:
    pass
# You could have also simply used result = list(response.results)[-1]

if result is not None:
    print(f"The answer is {result.text}".format(result.text))
```

If you plan to use this program with simple linear equations using only the x variable then you could do something like this:

```
print("The answer is {}".format(eval(result.text.replace("x = ", ""))))
```

However, this would not work with inputs such as `2x=y+3`.

Possible inputs include equations such as:

- `2x=5`
- `x-3=2x+2`

etc.

Comment: this looks better: `result = list(res.results)[-1]`

Comment: @furas I agree that it looks better and cleaner. Usually I prefer to use iterators in my way because elements could exceed memory bounds if loaded all at once. But in this case it's probably not going to happen, so thanks for your comment

Comment: Why do I get this error : `Undefined variable 'res'`

Comment: @Codin'friends There was a typo in my answer. Fixed. Let me know if it works now!

Comment: Thanks, It works but I was wondering if there is a way to output the result in decimal like - input: `2x = 5` wanted_output: `2.5` current_output: `5/2`